# VeraCrypt system recovery without rescue disc

Tags: windows-7, boot

I have a Windows 7 machine with the system partition encrypted by VeraCrypt. After a recent reboot, I'm getting a message saying that no boot sector was found. I also can't find my rescue disc USB.

I know my own password, but I don't know how to get to the point where I can enter it. I tried to fix the partition table/MBR, but was not successful.

Comment: You are out of luck, you need the recovery disk, in order to have any chance of recovery.